# React props and states

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components. Parent-Component 1 has a Child Component 2 I have an onClick function in Component 1 that opens up Component 2. But when I call Component 2, Component 1 stays open. I want when I open a Component 2 Component 1 closes .And also Component 2 has a backIcon, I want when i click on that Icon brings me back to Component 1. Its basically the same as in Google Chrome when you want to go back

```
Component 1
const MainSettings=()=> {
const [isSystemOpen, setIsSystemOpen]= React.useState(false)


    function openSystem(){
        setIsSystemOpen(true)
      }
      function closeSystem(){
        setIsSystemOpen(false)
      }
   

<ComputerIcon onClick={openSystem} />
                {isSystemOpen ? <System />: null}



Component 2

const System=(props)=> {


return(

        <div className='mainSystem'>
            <BackIcon />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called conditional rendering in react. I am assuming it as a simple case.

Providing a sample code for your solution. But if it does not fulfill your need, Please Explain your problem with specific points.

```js
Component 1
const MainSettings=()=> {
const [isSystemOpen, toggleSystem]= React.useState(false)


    toggleSystemComponent = () =>{
      toggleSystem(!isSystemOpen)
    }
   

       <ComputerIcon onClick={()=>toggleSystemComponent} />
       {isSystemOpen ? <System />: null}



Component 2

const System=(props)=> {


return(

        <div className='mainSystem'>
            <BackIcon />
        </div>
```